# How do I avoid using insert for a dictionary to increase performance?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        image = imread(f"Images/{i}.jpg")
        featureMatrix = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))

        for j in range(0, image.shape[0]):
            for k in range(0, image.shape[1]):
                featureMatrix[j][k] = ((int(image[j, k, 0]) + int(image[j, k, 1]) + int(image[j, k, 2])) / 3)

        features = pd.Series(np.reshape(featureMatrix, (image.shape[0] * image.shape[1])))

        df[f"{i}"] = features

    except:
        pass

df.to_csv("Features.csv")
```

And when I run it I get a PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()` when 'df[f"{i}"] = features' is run

I have tried using pd.concat but I am cannot get it to work. Any ideas on how I should replace the line?

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance and optimize processing avoid inserting a new *Series* into a dataframe on each of 1000 iterations. 
Instead yield all *series* (with setting their `name`) with a generator function and concat them at once with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def collect_features():
    for i in range(1000):
        try:
            image = imread(f"Images/{i}.jpg")
            featureMatrix = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))

            for j in range(0, image.shape[0]):
                for k in range(0, image.shape[1]):
                    featureMatrix[j][k] = ((int(image[j, k, 0]) + int(image[j, k, 1]) + int(image[j, k, 2])) / 3)
            yield pd.Series(np.reshape(featureMatrix, (image.shape[0] * image.shape[1])), name=f"{i}")
        except:
            pass

pd.concat(list(collect_features()), axis=1).to_csv("Features.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this alternative approach ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

df_list = []

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        image = imread(f"Images/{i}.jpg")
        featureMatrix = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1]))

        for j in range(0, image.shape[0]):
            for k in range(0, image.shape[1]):
                featureMatrix[j][k] = ((int(image[j, k, 0]) + int(image[j, k, 1]) + int(image[j, k, 2])) / 3)

        features = pd.Series(np.reshape(featureMatrix, (image.shape[0] * image.shape[1])))

        df_list.append(features)

    except:
        pass

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
df.to_csv("Features.csv")
```